# Why does the first django migration on an empty project take so much time?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

The first django migration on an empty project takes a lot of time

In my server, I wanted to test the installation of django. But after creating the project, I notice that the migration takes a lot of time.
I have searched the web but I only find examples of projects that have already modified the code generated by `django-admin`.

Here are the commands I did:

```bash
django-admin startproject test_dj
cd test_dj
./manage.py migrate # This take long time
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there are still some tables that Django has to create even if your project is empty, you can check it by opening a DB admin and see the tables created, some of them are for auth and the default admin.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience with django, this has never happened.

When migrations are run on an empty project, the default tables / tables required for specific middleware are created. Have you tried checking if the database is not an issue here?

Checking the SQL commands being run when applying a migration and running them manually might help debug it better. You can use this command to see the actual SQL being run.

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate <app-name> <migration-number>
```